Connecting to On-Premise SQL Server with Azure Data Factory via On-Premises Data via Express Route
Our service provider has deployed Data Gateway to our DataCentre via Express Route.
They have deployed Data Landing Zone - Virtual Network Data Gateway. The virtual network (VNET) allows for the secure connectivity to data sources associated with the VNET.
The connection to our On-prem resources look like the following:

I have never connected to an on-prem resource with Azure Data Factory via Data Gateway like this before. Although I'm sure its not very difficult.
Can someone provide some guidance on how to go about connecting to our On-prem data sources, specifically out SQL Server via our Exrpress Route VNET?
I believe I have to configure a Private Endpoint via DataFactory, but I'm not 100% sure

So I believe I will need to configure something like the following for Azure Data Factory, but like an expert to confirm


When connecting Azure Data Factory (ADF) to on-premises SQL Server, setting up a data gateway is not necessary. Instead, ADF provides a straightforward way to establish this connection using a Self-hosted Integration Runtime (IR). This runtime allows you to access on-premises data securely. You can follow Microsoft's official tutorial on creating and configuring a self-hosted integration runtime for step-by-step guidance.

@PratikLad, we have setup an Express Route to our on-premise resources. As a result we are connecting to the on-premise resources via VNET, as I showed you in the diagram. I just need recommendation on how to connect via Express Route VNET with Data Factory
